# convert a series of strings to a series of pandas Timestamp objects

Tags: python, pandas

The way I am doing this looks inefficient, so I figured that there had to be a better way that I am just not seeing.

Current approach:

```
dates = pd.DataFrame(['2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2017-05-24', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01',
     '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2020-01-11', '2019-11-01'], columns=['string'])
dates['timestamp'] = [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in dates['string']]
```

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: dates['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['string']) this will works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code did the trick for me:

Since I am using inbuilt function and it is a vectorized operation. This would be relatively faster.

`dates['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['string'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function if you don't want to use a python list comprehension

```
dates['timestamp'] = dates['string'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Won't be all that much faster but is a little cleaner imo